# Dualboot existing Windows and new Linux with LVM for everything

Tags: partition, windows, lvm

I have an existing Windows 11 system and I want to set up a dualboot with Arch Linux.
I haven't done any partitioning yet.
I want to be able to dynamically allocate more disk space to the Arch Linux system in the future (removing it from the windows system), so I think an LVM that spans everyting should be the right option.

Is it possible to set this up without wiping the existing Windows system?
If not, are there other ways to achieve this flexibility?

Comment: LVM will not suits your need due to the method. for example your C: Drive is 512 GB full and you shrink it in order to have 256GB for LVM you will be able to create a 256GB LVM for Arch partition, then later on you shrink again windows partition to 192GB. LVM will not be able to add the 64 GB freed as they will be before its start.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is to shrink your existing Windows and install Arch with LVM. If you later want to shrink Windows further you could create a new partition in the unallocated space and add that to the volume group. You could do that multiple times if you chose to. Going the other way would be harder but not impossible.

It’s not elegant but should work.